# Good scripting language/framework for recreating polynomial root calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting, polynomial-math

I was just wondering what the best online scripting language is to use for "simple" mathematical calculations, like solving for roots in 2nd 3rd or 4th degree polynomials.

For example, creating a little web "applet" like the one found [here](http://www.akiti.ca/Quad2Deg.html) which inserts the values inputed into the text boxes and inputs them as variables into the "quadratic equation" and solves for two x values.

Is plain JavaScript the best scripting language to use for this?  IMO, there's really no need for this to be server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to do this in a web page, pretty much your only choice is Javascript anyway. You *could* write a Java applet, but that's a pain and requires that people install the Java browser plugin.

Comment: OK, what is the best way to accept user input and then set that equal to a variable?

Comment: uhh ... you mean set a variable equal to the input I'm guessing. Well, you'd make a page with a form in it, and then set up Javascript event handlers for something like a "Go" button. That'd find the input fields in the form, grab the values, and start computing.  You sort-of have to know the basics of HTML and Javascript to get rolling on something like this.